# Get Latest "n" retweeter's followers for each of latest n tweets of a handle

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

I'm just trying to figure out to what is the best possible way to compute with the data coming from twitter. I have a problem at my hand,

- i have to get n number of latest tweets from a handle.
- With that find the n number of retweeters of each tweet.

  ```
  if(isset($_GET['handle'])){
      $tweets = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='.$_GET['handle'].'&result_type=recent&count=20');
      $data['ex'] = $tweets;
      $data['tweet'] = array();
      $data['tweeters'] = array();
      foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
           array_push($data['tweet'],$tweet->id_str);
          }
      var_dump($data['tweet']);   
      foreach ($data['tweet'] as $tweters) {
          $retweeters_ids = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweeters/ids.json?id='. $tweters .'&count=10');
          var_dump($retweeters_ids);

      }
  }
  ```

  i know the above code is bad because i can't put a get request inside **foreach**. 
  So, if someone has a better a way to solve this issue. Rate limit was problem i figured out after trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with separate scripts that run in separate moments (otherwise I hit the rate limits).